# How do i get submitted form (inputs like name="array[key]") type data as array/object in js to use in submit callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have form in which i am submitting multiple inputs containing name attributes as array like `name="array[key]"`

```
<form onsubmit="callback($(this));">
    <input type="text" name="stock[quantity]">
    <input type="text" name="stock[old]">
    <input type="text" name="form[mrp]">
    <input type="text" name="form[price]">
</form>
```

I have tried new `formData($("form")[0])` and jQuery `$("form").serializeArray()` both returning `name="array[key]"` as string.

I want this data as multidimensional object like we got this in php when submit this form like.

```
<script>
function callback($form){
    /* 
        here i want form data in js object like
        {
            stock : {quantity : ... , old : ....},
            form : {mrp : ... , price : ....}
        }

        or something like this
    */
}
</script>
```

> I am using JS, jQuery, and Vue.js in this project, actually i want to put this form data to indexedDB after successful save on server. i have different tables/objectStore for `stock` and `form`

Comment: you either need to write a compele logic or you can use this https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Serialize-Form-Data-Into-JSON-Object-In-jQuery-serializeToJSON.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```js
function callback($form) {
  let result = {};
  let formData = $form.serializeArray();        
  formData.forEach(obj => {
         let inputValue = obj.name.split('[');                 
           if (!result[inputValue[0]]) {
              result[inputValue[0]] = {};
           }
         let innerText = inputValue[1].replace(']','');
         result[inputValue[0]][innerText] = obj.value;
  });
  console.log(result);      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onsubmit="callback($(this)); return false;">
   <input type="text" name="stock[quantity]">
   <input type="text" name="stock[old]">
   <input type="text" name="form[mrp]">
   <input type="text" name="form[price]">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You probably want to cancel the form submission

Comment: prevented form submission for output readability @epascarello